# How to retrieve specific data from an JSON array?

Tags: html, json

Below is the Json Array which is the output.And I want to retrieve only name and description from this array.I want the result to be into an table within an HTML page.
Please help me out.

```
(
            [columnId] => 258f2200948711e3b4507b78fb18a9a7
            [columnName] => To-do
            [tasksLimited] => 
            [tasks] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [_id] => 5f4d17eeff71cf48f8cf033db78c5755
                            [name] => test
                            [description] => 
                            [color] => yellow
                            [columnId] => 258f2200948711e3b4507b78fb18a9a7
                            [totalSecondsSpent] => 0
                            [totalSecondsEstimate] => 0
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [_id] => ed30db48426da335d7b232d2d8c5b4f0
                            [name] => Write report
                            [description] => 
                            [color] => red
                            [columnId] => 258f2200948711e3b4507b78fb18a9a7
                            [totalSecondsSpent] => 0
                            [totalSecondsEstimate] => 0
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [_id] => ed30db48426da335d7b232d2d8e51eee
                            [name] => szxfasdfasdf
                            [description] => 
                            [color] => yellow
                            [columnId] => 258f2200948711e3b4507b78fb18a9a7
                            [totalSecondsSpent] => 0
                            [totalSecondsEstimate] => 0
                        )



                )

        )
```

Comment: That's not JSON.  You can find an [example here](http://json.org/example.html).

Comment: Then. you mean to say its just an array?

Comment: From where you get this JSON value?

Comment: To exapand on @AdamZuckerman's comment you can use `json_encode($array)` to serialize a structure to json.

Answer (score 0):

To access whatever element you want in that JSON you'll have to loop through it.

Lets say that you have an Object called **tasks_details**

```
    var tasks_details = your_array['tasks'],
        tasks_no = tasks_details.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < tasks_no; i++)
    {
       $('.your_table').append('<tr><td>' + tasks_details[i].name + '</td>\
 <td>' + tasks_details[i].description + '</td></tr>');
    }
```

A sample code would be like the previous, now stays to your choice how to fill your table.

Comment: thank u first off all. what does this "your_array" mean.